# I want to write a test to get code coverage for displaying a set of records in a table in a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have an apex code as below:

```
<apex:page controller="mySecondController" tabStyle="Account">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
    You belong to the {!account.name} account.
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!account.Contacts}"
                    var="contact"
                    cellPadding="4" border="1">
      <apex:column >
        {!contact.FirstName}
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column >
        {!contact.LastName}
      </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And a class code as below:

```
public class mySecondController {
  public Account getAccount() {
    return [select id, name,
            (select id, firstname, lastname
             from Contacts limit 5)
            from Account where id =
             :System.currentPageReference()
             .getParameters().get('id')];
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site mounica — going to close this question as it's been flagged, and is specific particularly to your scenario. Any answers would not help others in the future. The best route to take is to start your test code, then if you hit trouble ask a new question, showing the code and showing where you're stuck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific to the user's scenario only and will not aid anybody else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@isTest
private class TestClass {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
         Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
         insert a;

         Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'Joe', LastName = 'Schmoe');
         insert c;

         PageReference pg = Page.YourPageName;
         Test.setCurrentPage(pg); 
         string accId = a.Id;     
         System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id',a.Id);

         mySecondController controller = new mySecondController();
         Account myAccount = controller.getAccount();
         system.assertEquals(a.Id, myAccount.Id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from SOBJECT:Account to LIST<Account> at line 16 column 10

Comment: My bad, I thought your method returned a list of accounts, not a single account.  Just updated the code.  Try that

Comment: There should be at least one assertion in every unit test, otherwise you're not really testing anything.

Comment: I agree.  Just that all he was asking for was code coverage.  You are correct though, so I updated the code